# ASP.NET Client-side localization and Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I am building a web-based application which supports French language. 
When in ASP.NET I set the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture to fr-FR. Everything work in ASP.NET in French format which is great.
However if I have a code such as below, I run into incompatibility issues between ASP.NET and Javascript:

```
var value = <%:Model.Amount%>;
var total = value * 12;
```

The above will be rendered as:

```
var value = 1023,00;
var total = value * 12;
```

And get the following error message from the browser:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number*

Is there anyway to tell the browser what locale to work with? I tried the "accept-language" meta tag and that did not help.

**NOTE:** I am not looking for finding out how I can render the decimal values into the screen without culture, well aware of:

```
<%:Convert.ToString(Model.Amount, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(""))%>
```

I am looking for a way to tell the browser what my locale is, so that I wouldn't have to go through all pages of the project and see where things are breaking and change them.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried accounting.js http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/

accounting.js is a tiny JavaScript library for number, money and currency formatting, with optional excel-style column rendering (to line up symbols and decimals). It's lightweight, fully localisable and has zero dependencies.

or

```
<%:Model.Amount.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").Replace(",", "")%>
```

Comment: the problem is I cannot go through all the project pages and find out where in the source code a number values is being rendered. That would not be considered as an answer I am looking for.
I know how to manually remove culture in "ToString" calls, but this effectively causes an entire application rewrite.